# Extract part of string from a string?

Tags: c#, regex, string, visual-studio-2013

Hi i am having a problem with my application i want a part of string from a string.The situation is i am having a string variable named as `stringData` it stores following values:

```
IP Address         Hardware Address         Lease expiration                Type
192.168.1.2        00-23-8B-87-9A-6B        Mon Jan 02 01:14:00 2006        Dynamic
192.168.1.3        F8-F7-D3-00-03-80        Mon Jan 02 01:14:00 2006        Dynamic 
192.168.1.4        F8-F7-D3-00-9C-C4        Mon Jan 02 01:14:00 2006        Dynamic 
192.168.1.5        F0-DE-F1-33-9C-C4        Mon Jan 02 01:14:00 2006        Dynamic
```

I just want `Hardware Address` starting with `F8-F7-D3-00`. I am using a `substring` method now but i am getting only one matched hardware address but there might be a possibility of multiple strings as in above e.g and i want all of them.I am using C#.
Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: How you are using the `substring()` at the moment?

Comment: Is stringData a single line or the whole table-like text?

Comment: Robert..It is a table like text

Comment: //int index = stringData.IndexOf("F8-F7-D3-00");
           //     //string sub = stringData.Substring(index, 17);
           //     //Console.WriteLine(sub);

Comment: Is the whole table stored in a single string variable? Are the columns separated by tab or spaces?

Comment: @SaadAhmed: are you reading the data from file?

Comment: It is stored in a single variable.It is an output of a telnet command running via C# .

Comment: @SaadAhmed:one more question :1)how are you seperating the lines using newline character `\n`? 2)how are you seperating each column data using tab character `\t`? or fixed number of space characters?

Comment: Sudhakar Tillapudi..this is the thing where i am getting confuse i just applied search on a whole string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
string pattern = @"(F8-F7-D3-00\S+)";
string input = "IP Address         Hardware Address         Lease expiration                Type\n"+
    "192.168.1.2        00-23-8B-87-9A-6B        Mon Jan 02 01:14:00 2006        Dynamic\n"+
    "192.168.1.3        F8-F7-D3-00-03-80        Mon Jan 02 01:14:00 2006        Dynamic \n"+
    "192.168.1.4        F8-F7-D3-00-9C-C4        Mon Jan 02 01:14:00 2006        Dynamic \n"+
    "192.168.1.5        F0-DE-F1-33-9C-C4        Mon Jan 02 01:14:00 2006        Dynamic";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hardware Address: {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into separate lines first like this:

```
        string[] linesep = new string[] {"\r\n"};
        string[] dataLines = stringData .Split(linesep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then apply your Substring method to each:

```
foreach (line in dataLines)
{
    if (line.Contains(yourIPstring)
    // .. do your stuff
}
```

You may have to change the line separators.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Regular expression

```
var file = File.ReadAllText(@"....\Input.txt");

Regex r = new Regex("F8-F7-D3-00(-[0-9A-F]{2}){2}");
var matches = r.Matches(file);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string contains tabs you could split it by '/t' (a horizontal tab).

```
string hardwareAddresses = stringData.split('/t').ToList().Where((item, index) => index % 4 == 1);
```

hardwareAddresses will then contain an array of hardware addresses